# iconv error for PHP 5.3 when compiling

Tags: osx-lion, compile, php5

I get this error:

```
 -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -licucore -lm  -o sapi/cgi/php-cgi
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _convert in encodings.o
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _convert in encodings.o
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _convert in encodings.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1
```

I tried many tricks found online but it did not work. I tried to patch ext/iconv/iconv.c and recompiling iconv without luck. I am running OSX 10.7.4